# PyQt5 Shortcut does not work all the time

Tags: python, pyqt

So I build a GUI with PyQt5 and made a Shortcut für my Sub-Menubar like this:

```
        ''' Menubar '''
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()

        ''' Sub-Menubar '''
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Options')
        Pathfinder = QAction('Choose Folder', self)
        Pathfinder.setShortcut("Shift+L")
        Pathfinder.triggered.connect(lambda: self.clicked_menu(0))
        fileMenu.addAction(Pathfinder)
```

Pressing Shift + L works fine... as long as my mouse cursor is not active in an element. For instance if I change the value in one of my spinBoxes and the cursor (=caret) is "blinking" inside the spinBox, Shift+L does nothing.

```
        self.spinBoxMaxHolesPerCycle = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBoxMaxHolesPerCycle.setGeometry(485, 310, 45, 20)
        self.spinBoxMaxHolesPerCycle.setMaximum(200)
        self.spinBoxMaxHolesPerCycle.setValue(100)
        self.spinBoxMaxHolesPerCycle.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.changedValue(11))
```

Is there a way to work around this issue without clicking somewhere else to "deattache" the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're facing is not related to the mouse cursor, but is due to the keyboard *focus* (you *can* set the focus to a widget by clicking on it, though).

The problem is that QSpinBox widgets contain a QLineEdit that is used to edit the value using the keyboard, and since your shortcut *could* be interpreted as text (the upper case "L" letter), the widget automatically "eats" the keyboard event, preventing it to be propagated to the parent.

If you only care about a single widget, you could subclass it and override its `keyPressEvent`, and if it does not match the shortcut, just call the base implementation.

Since you may want to apply the behavior to more than one widget, a solution would be to install an event filter on the QApplication and check for key press events: if the event matches your shortcut, just trigger the action and return True.

```
        # ...
        # make the action an attribute, so that it can be accessed from elsewhere
        self.pathfinderAction = QtWidgets.QAction('Choose Folder', self)
        # ...
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QWidget) and 
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress):
                sequence = QtGui.QKeySequence(int(event.modifiers()) + event.key())
                if sequence == self.pathfinderAction.shortcut():
                    # the event matches the shortcut
                    self.pathfinderAction.trigger()
                    return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```