# How to obtain Shortcut Keys in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 Menubar program, I cant able to use Short cut Keys. For example, if I Press **Alt+X** , it will quit but a the same time if I Press Cntrl+X no action will take place. How to activate both shortcut keys, that is both Alt+X and Cntrl +X.

```
import sys,os

from PyQt5.QtGui import  *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Class_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Assist")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        mymenu = self.menuBar()
        mymenu.setStyleSheet("font-family: Trebuchet MS;font-style: normal;font-size: 10pt;font-weight: bold;")

        mymenucompany = mymenu.addMenu("&Company")

        mymenucompany_new = QAction("New",self)
        mymenucompany_new.setShortcut("Ctrl+Alt+N")
        mymenucompany.addAction(mymenucompany_new)

        mymenucompany_open = QAction("Ope&n",self)
        mymenucompany_open.setShortcut("Alt+N")
        mymenucompany.addAction(mymenucompany_open)

        mymenucompany_close = QAction("Close", self)
        mymenucompany_close.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        mymenucompany.addAction(mymenucompany_close)

        mymenucompany.addSeparator()

        mymenucompany_exit = QAction("E$xit", self)
        mymenucompany_exit.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+X"))
        mymenucompany.addAction(mymenucompany_exit)
        mymenucompany_exit.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)


        mymenuaccount = mymenu.addMenu("&Accounts")
        mymenuinventory = mymenu.addMenu("&Inventory")
        mymenumanufacture = mymenu.addMenu("&Manufacture")
        mymenupayroll = mymenu.addMenu("&Pay Roll")
        mymenureports = mymenu.addMenu("&Reports")
        mymenuotherss = mymenu.addMenu("&Others")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Class_MainWindow()
    mainwindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: With your code, the app correctly quits (at least on Linux), is it possible that you're using a widget that accepts text input (like a QLineEdit, or a QTextEdit)? If that's so, and they have input focus, a shortcut like Ctrl+X will be ignored by the program, as it's a common shortcut for the cut action of the clipboard (read this related answer [PyQt5 Shortcut does not work all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243551/2001654)). In any case, consider that, for the same reason, using Ctrl+X for anything not related to the clipboard is a very, **very** bad idea, especially for quitting...